# change background in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

For some reason, my background does not change and my game does not start when the space bar is pressed.  I am not receiving any errors, the program just isn't working correctly.  Please help.

```
def main():
    title = games.load_image("contratitle.bmp",transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = title
    cursor = Cursor()
    games.screen.add(cursor)
    xd = 0
    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_q):
        xd = 1        
        while xd == 1:
            screen = games.load_image("jungle.bmp", transparent = False)
            games.screen.background = screen
            file2 = 'contra.mp3'
            pygame.mixer.music.load(file2)
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            rizer = Rizer()
            games.screen.add(rizer)
            runner = Runner()
            games.screen.add(runner)
            shooter = Shooter()
            games.screen.add(shooter)
            spreadpower = Spreadp()
            #games.screen.add(spreadpower)
            rizerlives = Rizerlives()
            games.screen.add(rizerlives)
            rizerlivesa = Rizerlivesa()
            games.screen.add(rizerlivesa)
            #bean = Bean()
            #games.screen.add(bean)
    games.screen.mainloop()
main()
```

Then, I tried to use pygame.display.update(), but that didn't work either.  Am I putting it in the wrong place?

```
def main():
    screen = games.load_image("contratitle.bmp",transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = screen
    cursor = Cursor()
    games.screen.add(cursor)
    xd = 0
    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_SPACE):
        xd = 1
        while xd == 1:
            screen = games.load_image("jungle.bmp", transparent = False)
            games.screen.background = screen
            file2 = 'contra.mp3'
            pygame.mixer.music.load(file2)
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            rizer = Rizer()
            games.screen.add(rizer)
            pygame.display.update()
    games.screen.mainloop()
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

For your 7th line of code:

```
if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_q):
```

It appears you need to change it to:

```
if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_SPACE):
```

For more documentation on the PyGame gamekeys, see this link:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

Comment: I changed it, and the cursor disappears now, but the background doesn't change, and the game doesn't begin as usual.

Comment: @The Hawk 
I believe I know what your problem is.  You need to update the display during your while loop.  Use `pygame.display.update()`.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work.  I have updated my code in the area where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.